# Can library build in .NET 4.5 work in earlier versions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am building a c# class library using .NET 4.5 framework.

Can I use this library in ASP.NET applications built using 4.0 .NET framework?

Can anyone please help in providing solution how to make this work?

Comment: Due to the types moved among `mscorlib.dll`, `System.dll`, and `System.Core.dll`, what you want is almost impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility#Apps)

you should add supportedRuntime element in config file with supported version and recompile your class library

```
 <configuration>  
    <startup>  
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />  
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />  
    </startup>  
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

that depends on the library, if the library is supported in 4.0 .NET framework you should not get any issues.
try and if you faced an issue then you can just use 4.5 instead of 4.0 in your asp.net applications.

Answer (score 0):

1. Backup your project files.
2. Open your project with Visual Studio (MS VS 2013 for example), then use menu Project>Your_project Properties... to open [your project properties...] screen.
3. Click on Application section, Target framework and select the new .NET framework you want to use.
4. Restart MS VS to refresh the new selected configuration and rebuild the whole project to see if there is any compiling issue.
5. If there is any compiling issue, you need to fix it.
6. Test your app/library to see if it is still working well. If not, fix it.

In your app/library, if you didn't use any class, methods... which are available only in the your previous .NET framework selection, chances are that you don't have to fix anything after step 4.
Hope this help.